# How many ways can N labelled balls be placed in M unlabelled boxes, provided each box has at least P balls inside?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can $N$ labelled balls be placed in $M$ unlabelled boxes, provided each box must have at least $P$ balls inside?

Naturally $N > M \times P$.

Any closed form solutions would be great!

The motivation behind this question is that I want to brute force sample each of the possible configurations for particular values of $N$, $M$ and $P$. However, given that the quantity may be fairly large I want to check how many there are before trying!

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 1):

For $P=1$ the answer is given by the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

For general $P$, you have the  [$P-$associated Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Variants)